# PHP, split received POST data after few words or sentences

Tags: php, json

I am able to send JSONObject data from my application to server with PHP. I am also able to read the data. But now I want to send the data with a USER ID and type of data in the first two sentences. I am able to send this data from my application.

But I am not experienced with working on PHP and I dont know how to split this data after reading USER id and the type I have received and to store the rest of data separately ( and should be stored as json data with USER ID as filename).

Currently I am using the following to just save the

```
<?php 

$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($content, true);    

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
fclose($fp);    


if(!is_array($data)){
    throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
}

echo "Data Received";

?>
```

This is the json data format,

```
[{  "increment_id": "1", "uuid": "43c87b6e-4fd5-4f1b-9bba-3e512eb4787a", "xValue": "39.0", "yValue": "72.0", "inputTime": "Thu Mar 08 15:38:58" }]
```

I also want to attach user id with it, which I am able to attach and send it to server, but I cannot use json decode now as the format changes to re encode if I give a userid with it in the first sentence . So after attaching userid and type the data looks like this

```
UserID  Type [{ "increment_id": "1", "uuid": "43c87b6e-4fd5-4f1b-9bba-3e512eb4787a", "xValue": "39.0", "yValue": "72.0", "inputTime": "Thu Mar 08 15:38:58" }]
```

Comment: We'd need to see the data and what you want the results to be.

Comment: [{  "increment_id": "1",
  "uuid": "43c87b6e-4fd5-4f1b-9bba-3e512eb4787a",
  "xValue": "39.0",
  "yValue": "72.0",
  "inputTime": "Thu Mar 08 15:38:58"
 }]   This is the json data format, I also want to attach user id with it, which I am able to and sending it to server, but I cannot use json decode now as the format changes tp reencode if i give userid as seperate sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sentences? Send it where? Its far from clear what you are asking.

> I dont know how to split this data

We don't either. What do you mean by split? That implies there's going to more than one data item - where do you want to split it? What do you want to do with the 2 parts?

> should be stored as json data with USER ID as filename

It is very unlikely that it should be stored where you are currently putting it - particularly when you are applying no validation to the data you saved.

Consider (and note the differences with your script):

```
<?php 

define("DEST_DIR", "/not/in/your/document/root/");

$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($content, true);    
if (isset($data['USER'])) {
   $filename=basename($data['USER']);
   $filename="data_" . array_shift(explode('.', $filename) . 'json';
   file_put_contents(DEST_DIR . $filename);
   print json_encode(array('result'=>'success'));
} else {
   header("Bad Request", true, 400);
   print json_encode(array('result'=>'bad input data');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, currently I was only saving at root in local server just to test it, but will do the change to make a directory(Is there any more security things I should consider?). Your answer helped me, and one more mistake I made was not to make it a nested JSON data and easily get the required data. Now I am separating the required part by nesting it inside a variable.